# Adding HTML elements in a Django ModelForm

Tags: python, html, django

One of the fields in my form should display a static currency symbol as the first character in the field. This character should not be able to be deleted from the field. I understand that I can use `<span>` elements to insert the symbol into the field.

**The Problem**

I don't know how to put `<span>` tags around my form fields. Currently, this part of the site looks like the following:

forms.py

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = [
        'Date',
        'Time_Start',
        'Time_End',
        'Employee',
        'Client',
        'Service',
        'Price',
    ]
```

views.py

```
def jobs_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = JobForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('jobs'))
    else:
        form = JobForm()
    return render(request, 'home/jobs_edit.html', {'form': form, 'new_job': True})
```

page.html

```
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
    {% if new_job %}
        <h1>You are adding a new job</h1>
    {% else %}
        <h1>You are editing the details for job # {{ Job.Job_ID }}</h1>
    {% endif %}

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% form.as_ul %}

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

    {% if new_job %}

    {% else %}
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that by rendering fields manually. [We don’t have to let Django unpack the form’s fields; we can do it manually as we like](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) .